# Simple ToDo App using Agility.js with Persistence

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, agility.js

I created a database called `agilityjs` that has a table called `todolist`.  I created a file in `/api/todolist.php` which will act as a web service.  I want to make it so when the user clicks "New Item," it will add a new item to my database by calling the PHP file (`todolist.php`).  My next goal is to edit the item when they click to edit and delete when they click to delete.

Can anyone help me in the right direction?  I have seen the persistence documentation at http://agilityjs.com/docs/docs.html#persist but I'm not sure how to apply it.

The following code is simply taken from http://agilityjs.com/ (at the bottom, you can see it and it's live demo).

Here is another good resource for learning https://gist.github.com/3166678, but I can't seem to apply it either.

```
//
// Item prototype
//
var item = $$({}, '<li><span data-bind="content"/> <button>x</button></li>', '& span { cursor:pointer; }', {
  'click span': function(){
    var input = prompt('Edit to-do item:', this.model.get('content'));
    if (!input) return;
    this.model.set({content:input});
  },
  'click button': function(){
    this.destroy();
  }
});

//
// List of items
//
var list = $$({}, '<div> <button id="new">New item</button> <ul></ul> </div>', {
  'click #new': function(){
    var newItem = $$(item, {content:'Click to edit'});
    this.append(newItem, 'ul'); // add to container, appending at <ul>
  }
});

$$.document.append(list);
```

Thank you.